# Why does the the alert box pop up every second on the minute in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an alert box pop up on the hour. The minute it pops up, it pops up every second. Why is that so?

```js
function popup() {
    var today = new Date();
    var currentMinute = today.getMinutes();
    var currentHour = today.getHours();
        if ( currentMinute == "00") {
            alert("another hour has passed. it is now hour " + currentHour + " of the day!");
            }
       console.log( "popup" + currentMinute) ;   
          
}

setInterval(function() { popup(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Because of the last line of your code. setInterval to 1000, (1000ms = 1second)

Comment: 1000 == 1000 milliseconds == 1 second

Comment: However, in order for the function to excecute every hour I must set an interval, am I wrong?

Comment: Just set your interval like this 1000 * 60 * 60 insted of your 1000

Comment: @gmaarca you need to check the time every second, so you need the interval. If you want, you can add a variable to store the last checked time and make sure you dont check it again within the minute

Comment: @Talg123 If you do that, it will never show the alert unless the application is run at  0th minute.

Comment: @Herohtar , If I place currentMInute in popup function will it update then?

Comment: That looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a popup every second is because you have used `setInterval` with an interval of `1000` **milliseconds**, which is `1` second. So your `popup()` function gets called every second. Once the time reaches an even hour (for example, 3:00:00), the value of `currentMinute` will be `00` *for an entire minute*, so when your function gets called again a second later (3:00:01), the if statement still evaluates to true and the popup gets displayed again. And again at 3:00:02, 3:00:03, etc until it is 3:01:00.

You could either change your interval to 1 minute (`1000 * 60`) so that it never gets called more than once on the same minute, or set some variable that records the hour when the popup was displayed and check that as well.

Here is an example of the first method:

```js
function popup() {
  var today = new Date();
  var currentMinute = today.getMinutes();
  var currentHour = today.getHours();
  if (currentMinute === 0) {
    alert("another hour has passed. it is now hour " + currentHour + " of the day!");
  }
  console.log("popup" + currentMinute);
}

setInterval(popup, 1000 * 60);
```

Comment: when I set the interval to 1000 * 60, what happens is that the alert box does not show, do I make sense?

Comment: @gmaarca It will show, you just have to wait; it likely won't happen exactly when the minute changes. For example, if you started the function at `2:59:45` (45 seconds after 2:59) then the alert for 3:00 won't pop up until `3:00:45` (45 seconds after 3:00)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the popup to occur in the first second of the hour you still need to check the time every second. If like @herohtar says you place a variable in the popup code you can restrict the popup to just once per hour.

Code below is based on your code, I've done minimal refactoring to keep it simple:

```
var hourOfLastPopup = -1;

function popup() {
  var today = new Date();
  var currentMinute = today.getMinutes();
  var currentHour = today.getHours();
    if ( currentMinute === 0 && hourOfLastPopup !== currentHour) {
      hourOfLastPopup = currentHour;
      alert("another hour has passed. it is now hour " + currentHour + " of the day!");
    }
    console.log( "popup" + currentMinute) ;           
}

setInterval(function() { popup(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty new, could you please clarify why hourOfLastPopup should = -1?

Comment: Its just an initial value that is a non valid hour. It needs to be a non valid hour so that no matter what the hour when the popup function is first called it will fire. For example if you set it to 0 and you ran the script at 23:50 the next hour is 00:00 so the if statement will fail because hourOfLastPopup was initialized to 0. you can initialize to any value as long as its not zero to twenty three.